# Interpretation of Excess Return

Tags: risk, index, beta, expected-return, return

How is **excess return** defined for a given asset?

There are altogether two different definitions for excess return used in the calculation of **alpha** and **beta** and I'm unable to understand which one should we apply to generate valid statistical factors.

**Definition 1**: Given by the difference between return rate of the stock and risk-asset (such as Treasury Bill) or $ER^{(1)} = R_i - R_f$

**Definition 2**: Given by the difference between return rate of the stock and return rate of the market index with same risk or $ER^{(2)} = R_i - R_M$

Answer (score 2):

They are **both** excess returns even though the standard convention is to talk about *risk premium* for $R_{t+1}-R^f$ and *excess return on the market* for $R_{t+1}-R_M$. If you believe in CAPM, then you need the former to compute:
$$\alpha= (\bar{R}-R_f) - \beta(\bar{R}_M-R_f)$$

By definition, the excess return is the payoff of **a portfolio with price zero** today, i.e. if today you buy asset i you pay 1\$ to receive $R_{t+1}^i$ tomorrow, the same goes for asset j. Going long 1\$ in i and short 1\$ in j we obtain today 1\$-1\$=0 and tomorrow $R^i_{t+1}-R^j_{t+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

For any returns $R_i$ and $R_j$, we call the difference $R_i - R_j$ an excess return. The difference between any two returns is an excess return. An excess return is the return on a zero cost portfolio (because you are equally long and short).

In particular, using returns in excess of the risk free rate is quite common:
$$R^e_i = R_i - R_f$$

#### Mathematical convenience of excess returns

Excess returns are often more mathematically convenient/elegant to work with than regular returns because the space of excess returns is a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), hence adding excess returns together or scaling them still gives you an excess return.

Let $R^e_1$ and $R^e_2$ be excess returns. Let $a$ and $b$ be [scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar). Then:

- $a R^e_1$ is an excess return (closure under scalar multiplication)
- $R^e_1 + R^e_2$ is an excess return (closure under addition)

The difference $R_{\mathrm{Apple}}-R_f$ is an excess return. Multiply by the scalar $2$ and you get $2R_{\mathrm{Apple}}-2R_f$ which is also an excess return.